# how DNA controls properties of cell?

Tags: dna

My textbook says:

> DNA is the heredity material which controls the properties and
>   potential activities of a cell.

I couldn't understand how it controls properties of cell?

Comment: I think your best plan is to keep reading.

Comment: What it means is that it controls the cells purpose. Skin cells have a different genetic makeup than brain cells.

Comment: This question is far to broad. You are essentially asking "what is molecular biology" - like @AlanBoyd suggests, keep reading, probably the rest of your textbook or one you will read in the future is about exactly this.

Comment: @BryanKrause,actually I want to understand the fact what is meant by property of cell?and what is meant by potential activities(transcription or translation...yeh??)

Comment: The production of all RNAs and proteins in the cell, including RNA and proteins that regulate expression of other proteins, and indirectly all the functions of those proteins. Everything. This is all of biology at the cellular level. That's why your question is too broad.